# Connecting an 8051 to a 2V SRAM

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, resistors, ram

I just ordered some serial ram to use with my microcontroller. My micro is actually AT89C2051-24PU and runs on 4-6VDC.

The ram [23K256-I/P](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/22100F.pdf) (according to the datasheet) runs on 2.7 to 3.6VDC.

From my schematic, I'm trying to control the RAM with GPIO pins P1.5 through P1.7 and read the status with P1.4.

I use a diode for the return data to prevent excessive voltage from the P1.4 pin from entering the RAM (or am I being too paranoid here?)

R1 and R2 is meant to be a voltage divider so that VCC for the ram is within limits.

I believe the 8051 GPIO pins only have the values high-impedance and ground, so I added pull-up resistors to the lower voltage to give a default value of 1 to the RAM input pins (unless I set any of the values to zero in the 8051 code).

Is the schematic satisfactory, and is there a better way to do this than to rely on resistors and the diode? I don't want to overheat and possibly burn the RAM chip. The simpler the circuit, the better.

[image: circuit]

Comment: Is there a reason you don't sub an AT89LP2052 for the AT89C2051?  Or go hunting for a 5V serial SRAM for that matter?

Comment: Price, convenience, and adaptability. It costs only $1.15 for the ram and $1.10 for the microcontroller.

Comment: Don't use a voltage divider (R1+R2) to power the RAM! Unless the current draw of the RAM plus pull-ups is very constant, or R1 and R2 are small, waiting a lot of current, you're likely to blow things up. Use a regulator or, at least, a zener and a resistor.

Comment: In any case, your design for the interface between them is hopelessly wrong. The RAM is NOT 5V-tolerant, so a direct connection between the two chips is not going to work, and the diode does nothing useful.

Comment: I see EFM8 µCs prices at below $1. Time to upgrade - those are 8051 compatible and run on the same 3V3 supply as your RAM.